# Laravel mongodb package installation problem

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

when I am writing this in cmd `composer require jenssegers/mongodb` or `composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs` this error is showing:

> Using version ^3.6 for jenssegers/mongodb ./composer.json has been
>   updated Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could
>   not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1**

> - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.3
> - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.2
> - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.1
> - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.6 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.6.0, v3.6.1, v3.6.2, v3.6.3].
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.0 requires illuminate/events ^5.8|^6.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/events[v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14,
>     v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24,
>     v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33,
>     v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1,
>     v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0,
>     v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1,
>     v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0,
>     v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.10.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.11.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.12.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.13.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.13.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.14.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.15.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.15.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.16.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.17.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.17.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.18.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - don't install illuminate/events v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
> - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.5.48, required as 5.5.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.48].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

What am I doing wrong? Laravel version is 5.5 mongoDB version is v4.2.3